# ST-Link Tool in elementary OS

Tags: software-installation

I'm trying to install a tool (ST-Link) to write programs to a STM32 micro controller.
Could you give me a hint how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

To install stlink in elementary OS, you will have to build it from source code. Please follow the instructions,

At first please install these required packages for stlink by executing,

`sudo apt install build-essential cmake libusb-1.0-dev libgtk-3-dev clang gcc`

Then please [download stlink](https://github.com/texane/stlink/archive/master.zip) and extract it to *stlink*(you can choose any name, but we will use it in the process.

Go to the stlink folder and execute the following commands,

```
make release
make debug
```

The debug target should only be necessary for people who want to modify the sources and run under a debugger. The top level Makefile is just a handy wrapper for:

`mkdir build && cd build`
`cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..`
`make`

You could install to a user folder e.g $HOME: `cd build/Release; make install DESTDIR=$HOME`
Or system wide: `cd build/Release; sudo make install`

Fixing cannot open shared object file
When installing system-wide (sudo make install) the dynamic library cache needs to be updated with the command `ldconfig`.

The above information is grabbed from [stlink's github repo](https://github.com/texane/stlink/blob/master/doc/compiling.md).